# Android DialogFragment not dismissing on taping outside of it

Tags: android, kotlin, dialog, android-dialogfragment

So I have a DialogFragment which I want it to be cancelable, the thing is that I need to apply match_parent as width and height to see the dialog in the screen well formated , but when clicking outside it does not dismiss the dialog

```
class InformationDialogFragment : DialogFragment() {

    lateinit var viewState: InformationDialogViewState

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setStyle(STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.ModalTheme)
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        val dialog = dialog
        if (dialog != null) {
            val width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
            val height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
            dialog.window!!.setLayout(width, height)
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
        val dialog = Dialog(requireContext(), R.style.MyDialog)
        dialog.window?.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT))
        dialog.window?.requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
        dialog.window?.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN)
        return dialog
    }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View {
        val binding: InformationDialogBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.account_information_dialog, container, false)
        binding.viewState = viewState
        return binding.root
    }
}
```

I don't need to put `isCancelable`, `setCancelableOnTouch`, `setCancelable` because the dialog itself is cancealable as default, and I have tried it all

when I remove the onStart code, the touch outside works and dismisses the dialog, but the dialog is all shown wrong and vertically

Answer (score 0):

Changing height to wrap content let me dismiss the dialog clicking outside of it

```
override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        val dialog = dialog
        if (dialog != null) {
            val width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
            val height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
            dialog.window!!.setLayout(width, height)
        }
    }
```